# Not being able to access id element to build object for JS list for Ajax post.

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My model contains two lists of the `Order` entity type, but differentiating only by the value of the `Status` property. When `Orders` are created, the `Status` property is automatically set to `In Progress` and in the `AdminOrders view`, placed in the `Orders In Progress table`. The `AdminOrders view` has two tables: `Orders In Progress table` and `Orders Dispatched table` which will be filled by the `Model`'s lists respectively.

When the `Status` value of `new orders` is changed from the drop down list to `dispatched`, and when the `update` button in the view is clicked, the `Ajax post request` should be triggered by the JavaScript click event - passing the `list of all updated orders` in the view to the Ajax post method. However, nothing seems to be happening when I run the application.

At each time, `multiple Order objects` can have their `Status'` changed which is why I thought a simple `Ajax update post request` would be suitable.

Here's the Model class:

```
public class AdminOrdersViewModel
{
    public List<Order> OrdersInProgress { get; set; }
    public List<Order> OrdersDespatched { get; set; }
    public List<Status> OrderStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller GET action for the AdminOrders view:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminOrders()
{
    var inProgressOrders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == "In Progress").ToList();
    var despatchedOrders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == "Despatched").ToList();
    var statuses = new List<Status> {
        new Status { StatusName = "In Progress" },
        new Status {StatusName = "Despatched" }
    };

    return View(new AdminOrdersViewModel { OrdersInProgress = inProgressOrders, OrdersDespatched = despatchedOrders, OrderStatuses = statuses });
}
```

My post ajax method is here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateOrders(List<UpdatedOrder> UpdatedOrdersList)
{

    foreach (var item in UpdatedOrdersList)
    {
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return View("AdminOrders");
}
```

It should update every order that has had it's `Status` property changed and then update the view page.

This is the class for UpdatedOrder:

```
public class UpdatedOrder
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string newstatus { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, there is a list which is being passed. This list is collected from the JavaScript method in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Order-Update-Button").click(function () {

            var ListOfUpdatedOrders = []

            @{

                foreach (var item in Model.OrdersInProgress)
                {
                    @:ListOfUpdatedOrders.push({ id: "@item.OrderId", newStatus: document.getElementById("@item.OrderId") });

                }

            }

            var dataJson = JSON.stringify({
                "UpdatedOrdersList": ListOfUpdatedOrders
            });

            alert("running");
            // Perform the ajax post
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("UpdateOrders", "Manage")",
                data: dataJson,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("an error has occured!!!");
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

The `ListOfUpdatedOrders` list will put together objects consisting of `Order Id` and `Status` attributes. The new Status is being extracted through `getElementById` and the id is set to the `OrderId` of each order object displayed in the view.

The full view page code is the following:

```
@model ValueVille.Models.AdminOrdersViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Orders";

}
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Order-Update-Button").click(function () {

            var ListOfUpdatedOrders = []

            @{

                foreach (var item in Model.OrdersInProgress)
                {
                    @:ListOfUpdatedOrders.push({ id: "@item.OrderId", newStatus: document.getElementById("@item.OrderId") });

                }

            }

            var dataJson = JSON.stringify({
                "UpdatedOrdersList": ListOfUpdatedOrders
            });

            alert("running");
            // Perform the ajax post
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("UpdateOrders", "Manage")",
                data: dataJson,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("an error has occured!!!");
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>

<div class="main-content-container">

    <h1>New Orders In Progress<span id="update-order-test"></span></h1>

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <table class="panel panel-default table cart-table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Order ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Total
                </th>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.OrdersInProgress)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("OrderDetails", "Home", new { id = item.OrderId })">
                            @item.OrderId
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.OrderId)
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        £@item.Total
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Total)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.OrderDate
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.OrderDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.Status, new SelectList(Model.OrderStatuses, "StatusId", "StatusName"), new { @id=item.OrderId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                            }

        </table>

        <h1>Orders Despatched</h1>

        <table class="panel panel-default table cart-table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Order ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Total
                </th>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.OrdersDespatched)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("OrderDetails", "Home", new { id = item.OrderId })">
                            @item.OrderId
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.OrderId)
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        £@item.Total
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Total)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.OrderDate
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.OrderDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.Status, new SelectList(Model.OrderStatuses, "Id", "StatusName"))
                    </td>
                </tr>
                            }

        </table>

        <div class="panel-body form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input id="Order-Update-Button" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Chrome Console Error:

```
AdminOrders:60 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (AdminOrders:60)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
```

​

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code. You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943). If posting an array you need to stringify the data and set `contentType: 'application/json'`. Your `newStatus: document.getElementById(item.OrderId)` makes no sense and does not return the Status because of you invalid html

Comment: But why are you making an ajax call to post this anyway. Create a view model representing what you want that displays all orders with an associated dropdownlist (or just a checkbox if you only have 2 possible Status values - e.g. `bool IsDespatched`) and postback the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have **item.OrderId**.
 You can not get values like this

```
  for (var item = 0; item < @Model.OrdersInProgress.Count(); item++){
            var UpdatedOrder = { id: item.OrderId, newStatus: 
          document.getElementById(item.OrderId) };
            ListOfUpdatedOrders.push(UpdatedOrder);
  }
```

it should be

```
   @foreach (var d in Model.OrdersInProgress)
   {
            @:ListOfUpdatedOrders.push({ id: "@d.OrderId", newstatus: 
                "@d.Status.StatusName" });
   }

   var dataJson = JSON.stringify({
            'UpdatedOrdersList': ListOfUpdatedOrders,
    });

         //Perform the ajax post
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateOrders", "AdminOrders")',
            data: dataJson,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error has occured!!!");
            }
        });
```

**Update**

Change your dropDownlist

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.Status, new SelectList(Model.OrderStatuses, 
 "StatusName", "StatusName", item.Status), new { @id = item.OrderId })
```

and you should get newStatus like this

```
newstatus: $("#@item.OrderId").val()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason, the debugger is not getting passed the line where JSON is stringifying the list.

Comment: your welcome. How are you debuging that line. with chrome?. Did you check your **ListOfUpdatedOrders**

Comment: if you are using chrome,  can you post your exception from the console tab

Comment: I've updated the question and placed the error at the bottom.

Comment: I've updated my answer do not use `document.getElementById("@item.OrderId")`

Comment: Why should I not use getElementById()?

Comment: you are breaking your json :) if you insist use `document.getElementById("@item.OrderId").value`